# I have a query regarding deleting items from listView and notify changes in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have to delete items from listView In android and notify its changes.I have got some solution from StackOverflow but couldn't make it work.

This part of the code shows how i have initialised list view and call function from DAO class.

```
listvcard=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listofvcard);

         DAO dao = new DAO(getActivity());

         vcardadapter adapter = new vcardadapter(getActivity(), dao.getUser());

        listvcard.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    private class vcardadapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private List<VcardVO> listvcardVO;


        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public vcardadapter(Context c, List<VcardVO> list) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = c;
            this.listvcardVO = list;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
```

============================================================================

This part of the code shows how I delete Item from listView using ALertlayout.

```
h.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    deletepopup();
                }
                private void deletepopup() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    alert.setTitle("Delete this vCard?");

                    alert.setCancelable(false);
                    //alert.setIcon(R.drawable.vcardicon2);
                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)listvcard.getAdapter();
                            myAdapter.remove(myAdapter.getItem(position));
                            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
```

I am getting error in line `"ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)listvcard.getAdapter();"`

It says "vcardadapter cannot be cast to arrayadapter"

Please reply!! I am trying to resolve this issue from 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Add a method to remove the item from listview in Adapter given below:

```
public removeItem(int position){
         listvcardVO.remove(position);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And Call the method from Delete Button Click:

```
adapter.removeItem(postion);
```

Comment: "adapter" that i have declared above is not accessible in onClickListener of delete button.
I have created  method "removeItem"

Comment: How can i declare it globally.If I will declare public, it will show "error".

Comment: It tells "Remove invalid modifier"

Comment: Thank you sir  but I did that using listcardVO.remove(item).
But I have another query,how to delete  item from database in listView inn android.

Comment: Sir could you please tell me "how to delete item from database in listView inn android"

Comment: Yes sir I write some code but not working.
    

     Cursor cr=database.rawQuery("Delete from "+DataBaseAdapter.VCARD_TABLE+" where "+DataBaseAdapter.COLUMN_ID +" = "+ pos, null);  
     cr.moveToFirst();
     while (!cr.isAfterLast()) {
      listvcardVO.remove(position);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
     }